# What tools do I need to port packages to powerpc?

Tags: linux, llvm, powerpc

I'm relatively new to coding and building apps, and I wan to contribute to PowerPC Linux via packages.  So I'm trying to port apps and tools over to then package them for the platform and try to package them for different distro's such as ubuntu and void.  But, as it stands with running Ubuntu Mate 16.04, basically everything is out of date (LLVM, Clang, ETC) so I'm having to build stuff by hand to get other stuff built, which atm is Firefox 61.

No problem!  But, what all tools should I acquire?  And I have the system as up to date as I can make it by the way, the tools are just out of date.  I have the code for LLVM, clang, and associated tools, but I don't know what other tools I may need in the future (If I have Clang do I need GCC?  If an app calls for GCC in the build process can I bump it to clang instead?  What tools do I need for python?  Or rust?  What are your general recommendations for languages I should be up to date with?).

For note, I'm building on-platform via a powerbook G4 A1138.  Its a little slow, but its not that bad over all.  I know I could cross compile, but something doesn't sound right about building on X86 for powerpc. Like I'm gimping the platform by doing that.

Anyways, all the info I can get would be helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: Since it is a PowerBook you can probably use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) to install updated tools. I say *"probably"* because I am assuming you still run OS X 10.x (10.4 or 10.5?). I have a PoweMac running 10.5 and MacPorts is working fine with it.

Comment: Actually I'm running UBuntu Mate 16.04 AND OSX 10.5.  Though I only use 10.5 for gaming, linux is strictly for improving the platform.  I have an IDE to Sata adapter in it and have been looking for my spare 1TB SSHD that I have, but atm the 240GB HDD thats in it is doing fine.

IDK how stack overflow works, if theres a PM system or what, but if anyone wants to know why I'm doing this PM me haha.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is Long Term Support (LTS). It is supported until [2021](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle). Everything should be up-to-date (or as up to date as it can be with Ubuntu). Also see [How to install updates via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/196768) If it is missing patches then you should file a [Ubuntu Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect).

Comment: Its as up to date as it can be.  LLVM is just out of date so I'm going to build the tools I need from source and probably do a kernel upgrade.  I just want to know what tools I should probably get since, in my mind,. if LLVM is out of date and ignored, everything else is too.  And since I'm rather new at this IDK what tools I'll need.  UNtil last night I thought rust was an installable package but according to mozilla's docs I grab it off their site.  And I did.  So, literally. I have no clue what tools I may need in the future.

Comment: I think you need to rework your question. You need to clearly state what you have in one sentence, then clearly state what you are trying to build in another sentence. Then, show how things are going wrong for you when trying to build your package.

Comment: Does that work better?  Sorry, I have never used this site before ^^

Answer (score 1):

There is a clang-5.0 and [clang-6.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial-updates&arch=powerpc&searchon=names&keywords=clang-6.0) for powerpc in the Ubuntu repository.

The [PPA for Ubuntu Toolchain Uploads (restricted)” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) has very recent toolchaing for powerpc on 16.04 too.